# Handle Browser close in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to trap the browser closing event from JavaScript? I don't want to do this in Page Unload event or anything.  It must be handled on clicking the browser close button.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. You only have `onbeforeunload` event, available as raw javascript (jquery doesn't include this event).

If you want to try it, try to post here an answer and, without pressing "post your answer" try to close the browser window.

This is the closest way to access the "close window" event.

Comment: Isn't  "No" a little misleading answer?

Comment: No :) because the solution here is for browser tab close not for the whole browser close.

Answer (score 4):

onbeforeunload event captures every unload event but there is some trick way to handle if user closing browser by clicking close button, here is a sample code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
                    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    //handle if your mouse is over the document body,
    //if not your mouse is outside the document and if you click close button return message or do what you want

    var out = false;
    $("body").mouseover(function(){
      out=false;
    }).mouseout(function(){
      out=true;
    });


    $(window).bind('beforeunload', function(e){
    if(out)
        {return "Do you really want to leave this page now?"}
    });

  });
  </script>

</head>
<body>
  <p>   
    <a href="http://cssbased.com">go outside</a>
    <br>
    <a href="test.html">reload page</a>
    <span> </span>
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is nice article about this from [4guysfromrolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020134123/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/100604-1.shtml)

```
    <script language="JavaScript">
        window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
        function confirmExit()
        {
            return message to display in dialog box;
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really. Page unload event is all you have. And even that not always. It would provide the ability to interfere with user's wishes pretty bad.

Answer (score 0):

you can not call alert or any interface(like open modal dialog or something!) while closing, but you do something in background for sure with this function

```
window.onunload = function()
        {
            if ((window.event.clientX < 0) || (window.event.clientY<0)) // close button
            {
                //do something on closing event
            }
            else if (window.event.altKey == true) // ALT + F4
            {
                //do something on closing event
            }
            else // for all other unload events
            {
                //do something on closing event
            }
        }
```