# Perform action when browser tab is closed (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, events, browser, dom-events

I would like to be able to perform some action when the browser window/tab is closed. This should be done using Javascript. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `onBeforeUnload` handler. See this:

[Handle Browser close in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143194/handle-browser-close-in-javascript)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload

Update:

See this:

http://www.megasolutions.net/javascript/Accessing-new-URL-in-onbeforeunload---or-similar-effect-by-other-means-9527.aspx

> If there was a way to catch the unload
>   and prevent it happening then popup
>   adverts everywhere would use it to
>   prevent you closing the popups.
>
> A different approach would be to use
>   the onload event for your page to go
>   through all  tags in the page and
>   add an onclick handler which does what
>   you want.

Comment: which is triggered for any reason the page is left

Comment: This is about all you can do, but note that you can't ultimately guarantee that you won't have the browser disappear out from under you without warning or recourse.

Comment: @Pointy: +1, but you must assume this all the time.

Comment: Oh yes, of course :-)  I just meant to say that "beforeunload" is not magic, so a design can't rely on it to solve problems.

Comment: Is this the only solution? I'm sure I've seen other websites do this.

Comment: @Tomasz Kowalczyk: Indeed; however, some browsers have a hard time limit for *this* specific handler; when that expires, the script is unceremoniously killed.

Comment: Yes, this is the "last call" you can handle while closing browser window / tab.

Comment: i'm trying to get it to open a new window that browses to a new url...I want the original window to close (no prompts). This should still work, right?

Comment: I doubt if you can open new page while closing other one. See updated answer.

Comment: I found a solution but it is a little backwards. Basically, in the onBeforeUnload method, you can change the content of your page. so rather than browsing to a new link the content just gets changed (so it appears that you are browsing somewhere new).