# How to detect a close of a browser using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Handle Browser close in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143194/handle-browser-close-in-javascript)

How to detect a close of a browser using JavaScript or jQuery, I got the `window.onbeforeUnload` and `$(window).unload()` of JavaScript and jQuery respectively, but that even gets called on leaving of page,and etc... but I need only and only the close event, nothing  else and only that.

Comment: There is no reliable way. I have a solution that detects the user mousing up to the top right direction close button

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, but this is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).unload( 
function () { alert("You Are closing window"); }
);
```

is that what you mean

Comment: `alert("...or refreshing the page or going to a link");` Your answer does not answer what the poster wants. [which is impossible]

Comment: ok im sorry..my english is bad so i didn't understand him well